# No command found with name "focus"

Tags: react-native

When i click on textinput, there is this error. I danot know why

[click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7MWD.png)

Comment: Please edit the question and add some relevant code.

Comment: is this on IOS with react-native v63, im having the same error

Comment: Check wether you're using react-native-reanimated@2.*.* Issue reported here: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/2364#issuecomment-916795999

Answer (score 3):

Check if there isn't any code of yours trying to trigger focus on an element that doesn't support focus.

For example, in my case, I got this error when setting the `autoFocus` prop on an element different than `TextInput`, e.g. a `Button` or a `View`.

Comment: Writing code for the web (react native web) I found this to be true. I was trying to focus a Touchable component, which is not supported.

Comment: NativeBase's Modal's `initialFocusRef` is another dangerous prop to look out for. [Their docs](https://docs.nativebase.io/modal#h2-props) don't say anything about what type of elements are allowed, and in react-native-web, it's a good practice to pass the ref of a close button. Might expect they'd map this to accessibility focus on native but nope, they just call `.focus` and it crashes; need to wrap in `Platform.select({ web: refOfNonInputToFocus })`

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem while using react native, with an accompanying version mismatch problem between js (0.62) and react native (0.63). The app I am developing also shows bad keyboard behavior for TextInput. Solved all problems by downgrade react native to 0.62.0, like so:

- change the react native version # in package.json to 0.62.0
- $ rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock
- $ yarn install

So it's the version mismatch bug causing the keyboard focus issue in my case. Good luck!

Comment: Downgrading might be a workaround for some people but it's not a solution. I'm using version 0.64.